# Pass multiples values to script into sqlplus in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I want to execute the same sql script passing one text every time but I don't know how to it. I want to do it into sqlplus.

With this select I have the values but I don't know how to pass this values.

```
 select column_value from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('Logons Per Sec', 'Executions Per Sec')))

 LOOP 
   start script.sql column_name;
 END LOOP;
```

I don't understand your example. I have try to use but it doesn't works. I want to pass both values to "prueba.sql" (one in each execution)

```
cat prueba.sql
 prompt &1;

SQL> COL column_value NEW_VALUE v_column_value
SQL> select column_value column_value from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('Logons Per Sec', 'Executions Per Sec'));

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------
Logons Per Sec
Executions Per Sec

SQL> @prueba.sql &&v_column_value
Executions
```

I want to execute a report inside the prueba.sql each time with one of this values as parameter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COLUMN` command in SQL*PLUS as shown below.

```
SQL> COL column_value NEW_VALUE v_column_value
SQL> select column_name column_value from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('Logons Per Sec', 'Executions Per Sec')));

SQL> @"test.sql" &&v_column_value
```

**Documentation:** [COLUMN in SQL*PLUS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve013.htm#SQPUG034)

Comment: I don't understand your example. I have try to use but it doesn't works. I want to pass both values to "prueba.sql" (one in each execution)

    cat prueba.sql
    prompt &1;

SQL> COL column_value NEW_VALUE v_column_value
SQL> select column_value column_value from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('Logons Per Sec', 'Executions Per Sec'));

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------
Logons Per Sec
Executions Per Sec

SQL> @prueba.sql &&v_column_value
Executions
I want to execute a report inside the prueba.sql each time with one of this values as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Im not aware of a looping construct available in SQLPLUS so you will need to call prueba.sql twice - once for each returned parameter.

```
COL column_value NEW_VALUE v_column_value

SELECT rn, column_value
  FROM (
select rownum as rn,column_value from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('Logons Per Sec', 'Executions Per Sec'))
order by column_value desc)
WHERE rn = 1
/

@prueba.sql '&v_column_value'

SELECT rn, column_value
  FROM (
select rownum as rn,column_value from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('Logons Per Sec', 'Executions Per Sec'))
order by column_value desc)
WHERE rn = 2
/

@prueba.sql '&v_column_value'
```

The first line sets up a SQLPLUS attribute value which is populated by the query that returns 'column_value'.

The query orders by the name but selects each value based on it's ROWNUM after the ORDER BY. This should ensure that both queries return records in the same order but look at separate rows returned.

The use of the 'v_column_value' parameter is wrapped in single quotes as you have embedded spaces.